# Jsoup Can't parse a link correctly to HTML

Tags: java, jsoup

I've been using Jsoup for wile with Google Search Blog and every thing work just fine but when i used another web site like this one [WhosTalkin](http://www.whostalkin.com/search?q=boston&x=0&y=0) i couldn't extract the results data and links. My code :

```
Connection.Response response = null;
    String url = "http://www.whostalkin.com/search?q=boston&x=0&y=0";
        // 
        try {
             response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31")
                        .timeout(10000)
                        .execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
             System.out.println("io - "+e);
        }
        // get page title
        Document doc = response.parse();
        String title = doc.title();
        System.out.println("Page Title: " + title +"\n");
```

and here the part where i extract the data :

```
Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("h3");
        for (Element link : links) { 
            System.out.println("\nTitle: " + link.select("a").attr("title"));
            System.out.println("Result: " + link.select("a").attr("href"));
            }
```

and when i just want to make sure that Jsoup can't parse correctly HTML i used the [Try Jsoup](http://try.jsoup.org/) and fetch URL, He gave me HTML code that doesn't match with the code when i examine it with the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the right selectors. Look for the `drill` CSS class. It's easier to get to the elements.

```
Elements elementsByClass = parse.getElementsByClass("drill");
for (Element link : elementsByClass)
{
    List<Node> childNodes = link.childNodes();
    System.out.println("Title: " + childNodes.get(1));
    System.out.println("Result: " + childNodes.get(0).attr("src"));
}
```

**Prints**

```
Title:  Backtype
Result: http://www.whostalkin.com/img/backtype.png

Title:  FriendFeed
Result: http://www.whostalkin.com/img/friendfeed.png

...
```

Comment: Ok i didn't get what you told me about "drill" but first i want the result would be like that : Title : prayers for Boston and the... Results : www.linkhere . bottom of line i couldn't extract the results of the search that shown on the link

Comment: You mean the search results ? They are fetched dynamically. You cannot parse them readily with Jsoup since Jsoup does not evaluate the HTML's javascript.

Comment: Yes that what i meant, So is there any other alternative solutions? another parser my be ?

Comment: The query itself appears to be sourced from `/main.php?q=boston`. Use that.